# Uso de expresión Lambda en C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Teniendo las siguientes entidades

Entidad Carrera:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
namespace WebApiCarreras.Models
{
    public class Carrera
    {

        public Carrera()
        {
            Semestres = new List<Semestre>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public List<Semestre> Semestres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entidad Semestre:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApiCarreras.Models
{
    public class Semestre
    {
        public Semestre()
        {
            Cursos = new List<Curso>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Carrera")]
        public int CarreraId { get; set; }
        public Carrera Carrera { get; set; }
        public List<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entidad Cursos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApiCarreras.Models
{
    public class Curso
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Semestre")]
        public int SemestreId { get; set; }
        public Semestre Semestre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Atraves del controlador estoy intentando realizar a traves de expresion lambda obtener por ID La carrera, muestro un codigo de ejemplo a traves del controlador.

Controller:

```
//Para ver un pais por su ID
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "carreraCreado")]
        public IActionResult GetById(int id)
        {
            var carreras = _context.carreras.Include(x => x.Semestres).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);


            if (carreras == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(carreras);
        }
```

Esto me muestra atraves en el Body:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Desarrollo de Software",
    "semestres": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "I",
            "carreraId": 1,
            "cursos": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "II",
            "carreraId": 1,
            "cursos": []
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "nombre": "III",
            "carreraId": 1,
            "cursos": []
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "nombre": "IV",
            "carreraId": 1,
            "cursos": []
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "nombre": "V",
            "carreraId": 1,
            "cursos": []
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "nombre": "VI",
            "carreraId": 1,
            "cursos": []
        }
    ]
}
```

El error que en lambda no se aun como hacer que tambien me muestre la lista de cursos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: si puede cambia el titulo porque esto no tiene que ver con lambda, sino con entity framamework

Comment: Respecto a la expresión lambda lo utilizo en el controlador

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos la documetacion

[Loading Related Entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

veras en el titulo `Eagerly loading multiple levels` que se puede utilizar

```
var carreras = _context.carreras
                       .Include(x => x.Semestres.Select(p => p.Cursos))
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

en el `Include` defines el select a los cursos

Comment: puse el link en ingles porque la traduccion que hacia al español es horrible

Comment: InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression 'x => {from Semestre p in x.Semestres select [p].Cursos}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. Se produjo el siguiente error agregando tu solución.